# Activation Error and no access to Iphone

Tags: ios7, udid

I upgraded my Iphone IOS to 7 weeks ago.
Today automaticaly it has been upgraded to the last beta IOS and ask me for Activation. 
On display there's a text "Activation Error, register for developer program" and I have not access to my phone.

also, since i installed a new windows on my laptop, I didnot connect the phone to my itunes. Now for finding UDID I just connect it to Itune and Itune ask me to Trust the phone but i have not access to iphone to trust.

seems i have the option to downgrade to ios6 through dfu mode, but i need my data on it and it will be lost if i use udf/restore.

plz provide me solution

Answer (score 1):

This seems like it would answer your question: http://www.imore.com/how-downgrade-ios-7-beta-back-ios-6

Sometimes it's tricky knowing if you made it into DFU mode properly, this should help: http://www.iclarified.com/entry/index.php?enid=1034

Please be careful putting your primary phone on unstable versions of software, Apple has a nasty history of trying to prevent people from going backward.